# facebook php-sdk on localhost with zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I try to use facebook sdk-php library in my localhost with zend framework 2, My localhost zf2  application address is http://zf2.loc, I put it in "Website with Facebook Login" in my app on facebook but it is not working, what is my wrong ?

Comment: What's not working? You're getting an error? Can you show some code?

Comment: Get me as not connected while i am Actually login

Comment: I test with this code and i include facebook sdk-php in the zf2 vendor

<code>
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    echo 'connected';
}else{
    echo 'not connected';
}
</code>